# Determine the access a user has

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm prety adept at using fileacl to set permissions so understand access control lists reasoanbly well.

However, given a specific folder with a set of ACL applied to it, is there a utility to tell you which ACL is giving a certain access?

The reason I'm asking is that, for some reason, on a specific folder, I've personally got the ability to create folders but other users cannot. The later is the correct state of affairs but I've looked at the ACL and just cannot see how I'm getting write access. And no, I'm not domain or local administrator.

Something like:

UserAccess mydomain\username \server\data\folder1

Would display the access that user has on that folder. Windows obviously does all the time internally when determining what access a user has to a resource.

Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Mea culpa but it turned out, my account was a domain admin. Nobody has any recollection of adding me, including myself. However, it as very useful to be reminded about the effective permissions tab plus learn about the SubInACL tool which will be useful in other cases. Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 5):

You can view "Effective Permissions" on the security tab. It will let you put in a user name and show the effective permissions for that user on the object that you're inspecting.

Example:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy method to use:

1) create a new account with group membership like the "other users".

2) One by one, add the groups that you are in, but the other users are not members of, and check the effective permissions for that account in the Security tab.

Alternatively: just open the properties of the folder, and look at the group permissions one by one. These are not too mysterious, and if you click on the security object, and use the advanced view | edit, you can see each individual permission in a lot more detail.

Finally, this tool SubInACL looks like it would help you out: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23510